# Help with Javascript to C# converter

Tags: c#, javascript, converters

I find a algorithm writen by javascript,now i want to convert it to C#,
Any tool can do this?

Comment: Why not just do it yourself? If you have a tool do it for you, you will be at a total loss to fix any problems that may have occured during generation.

Comment: By chance, does the algorithm convert c# to javascript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you could start with [Javascript.Net](https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net) to try your code within another application before rewriting/converting it. Whatever you do, don't rely on auto-generated code for an algorithm of any importance.

If memory serves, there was actually a flavor of JavaScript that ran on the .Net CLR. I don't think it ever caught on.

Comment: For anyone who is curious about JavaScript for .Net: http://www.webreference.com/js/tips/020422.html.  Obviously, this is almost a decade old.

Comment: @Time: Javascript.Net is fine,i will try it

Answer (score 2):

Using javascript.net or jscript with .net Reflector, will save you brain and keyboard, may be

Comment: I am using jsc.exe compile javascript code to .net dll,and reference this dll in my C# project and call it's method,finally it work for me,thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a dialect of JavaScript called UnityScript that can be converted into C# using the [UnityScript-to-C# converter](http://www.m2h.nl/files/js_to_c.php).

I also wrote a tool called [universal-transpiler](https://github.com/jarble/universal-transpiler) can convert a small subset of JavaScript into C# and several other languages.

Input in JavaScript:

```
function add(a,b){
    var g = [3,4,5];
    return a+b+(g[0])+(g.length);
} 

function divide(a,b){
    return a/b;
}
```

Output in C# from universal-transpiler:

```
public static int add(int a,int b){
    int[] g={3,4,5};
    return a+b+(g[0])+(g.Length);
} 

public static int divide(int a,int b){
    return a/b;
}
```